# Aframe toogle active camera orbit-controls overriding look-controls from second camera

Tags: components, aframe

I am trying to toggle between 2 cameras using 2 buttons. The switch works flawless and as expected but there is one issue. The active camera is a camera with orbit-controls component, the second camera is a "rig" with constrainToNavMesh movement-controls component. The first camera works fine but on the second one after i switch i can only move(wasd) and lost the camera rotation/pan but when i switch to the first camera again the action of panning actually took effect in the first camera. Can someone please tell me what i have do wrong?

```
HTML
     <a-entity
        id="camara_principal"
        position="-5.481 -0.15 13"
        movement-controls="speed: 0.08; constrainToNavMesh: true">
        <a-entity
          id="camera_caminhar"
          camera="far: 2000;"
          position="0 1.6 0"
          look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false">
            <a-entity
              id="camera_box"
              geometry="primitive: box; active: false;"
              position="0 -0.3 0"
              aabb-collider="objects: a-box; collideNonVisible: true;"
              scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"
              material="opacity:0">
            </a-entity>
          </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity
          id="camera_orbita"
          camera="far: 2000;"
          orbit-controls="autoRotate: true; autoRotateSpeed: 0.2;target:-1.5 0 -1; minDistance: 13; maxDistance: 35; initialPosition: 0 7 35; maxPolarAngle:87; minPolarAngle:60;">
        </a-entity>
```

```
Javascript

function CamaraSecundaria(){
      var secondCameraEl = document.querySelector('#camera_orbita');
      secondCameraEl.setAttribute('camera', 'active', true);
         };

    function CamaraPrincipal(){
      var firstCameraEl = document.querySelector('#camera_caminhar');
      firstCameraEl.setAttribute('camera', 'active', true);
          };
```

```
(EDIT)Added pause(); and play(); to parent entity but still no success!

function CamaraPrincipal(){
      var firstCameraEl = document.querySelector('#camera_caminhar');
      firstCameraEl.setAttribute('camera', 'active', true);
      document.querySelector('#camera_orbita').pause();
      document.querySelector('#camara_principal').play();
          };
```

Thanks!
PS: This error only occurs on mobile version, when testing on the PC works fine.
Here is the link to the project https://www.digimatter.pt/PT/2camaras_teste.html

Comment: After digging and testing a bit further my conclusion is that orbit-controls are not actually overriding the look-controls component because in the desktop version works as expected but on mobile it does not. Using the mouse the mouseDrag event fires and when you drag  the mouse in one of the cameras the position gets updated on both cameras as expected. But on mobile the touchDrag event does not fire at all in look-controls but works fine with orbit-controls component so you cannot see the position changes in the camera with look-controls but they reflect in the camera with orbit-controls.

Comment: Can you create a glitch that illustrates the issue? Helpers can debug and easily suggest solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe FYI, The link in the question doesn't work.